# how to easily make a SOAP call.

Tags: soap

How we can easily add soap call page to applications ? If the magento installation is at mymagento.com what can be the soap call http request ?

i tried with $soap = new SoapClient('http://mercande.com/index.php/api/soap_v2?wsdl');

Comment: i solved it like <?php
$soap = new SoapClient('http://mercande.com/index.php/api?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$session_id = $soap->login('user,'apikey'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

//$result = $soap->call( $session_id, 'country.list' );
$product = $soap->call( $session_id, 'catalog_product.info', 'SMS001');
//echo $result[0]['country_id'];
var_dump($product);

Answer (score 3):

For magento version > 1.3, you can use below example:

```
<?php

$apiUser = 'api_user'; //The api user name you created in magento
$apiPassword = 'password'; //The api password
$wsdlUrl = 'http(s)://your-magento-domain/api/soap_v2?wsdl=1';


$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl);
$apiSession = $soapClient->login($apiUser, $apiPassword);

$params = array('filter' => array(
    array('key' => 'status', 'value' => 'pending'),
    array('key' => 'customer_is_guest', 'value' => '1')
));
$result = $soapClient->salesOrderList($apiSession, $params)

//End your session 
$client->endSession($session);
```

For more info, please refer: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html